# How to construct Split screen in libgdx? One for 2d animation and One for Information panel

Tags: java, android, split, screen, libgdx

I am trying to construct a layout like this picture:
[image]

Should I use two stages?, two cameras?, one stage with splitPane?
 I want the top screen to be half of the entire devices height. The top screen will have animated actors and a single background image with some labels close to the top of the screen.

The lower screen should be a Scrollpane with information and at the bottom ,the menu and back buttons.

How do I secure the ratio between them if the screen resizes?

Edit 2014-03-28:

Hi!

I tried using two stages as proposed and I am pretty happy. Thought I share my first try at it. The result was this code:

```
package se.appltini.mygdxtest;

//imports omitted

public class DualStageTutorial extends ScreenAdapter {

private Stage upperStage;
private Stage bottomStage;  
private Skin skin,menuSkin; 

@Override
public void show() {        
    upperStage = new Stage();
    bottomStage = new Stage();
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin/uiskin.json"));      
    menuSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("menuSkin/uiSkin.json"),new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("menuSkin/uiskin.atlas")));

    Image upperImage = new Image(menuSkin.getPatch("menuTexture"));
    upperImage.setFillParent(true);
    upperStage.addActor(upperImage);

    Image bottomImage = new Image(menuSkin.getPatch("menuTexture"));
    bottomImage.setFillParent(true);
            //setting alpha to 0.5f so we can see the different stages 
    bottomImage.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
    bottomStage.addActor(bottomImage);

}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        

    upperStage.act(delta);  
    bottomStage.act(delta);         

    /*Upper Half*/          
    //set the openGl viewport to half the screenheight and starting y from the     middle of the screen
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);      
    upperStage.draw();   

    /*bottom Half*/     
    //set the openGl viewport to half the screenheight and starting y from the     bottom of the screen
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);    
    bottomStage.draw();

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    upperStage.dispose();
            bottomStage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
            menuSkin.dispose();


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice here would be to use two different stages.

Using two stages will simplify design in sense that the viewport management for 2d animation will simplify by a considerable amount. Also the event handling has to be completely different style. Your information panel won't have much relative layout changes in actors as compared to 2d animation.

Using same stage would make sense only if both contents overlap each other in some form. I'm sure this is not the case here. Your info panel will always be ABOVE animation (most probably).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer and I edited the original post with the first try at it. Worked quite well.